# Make attendee as organizer in Google Calendar Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using googleapis npm package to create calendar events with.
This is my request payload for calendar.events.insert to create an event.

```
{
  "summary":"Biology class",
  "location":"Google Meet: Please follow the google meet url",
  "description":"Unit and Measurements",
  "colorId":2,
  "start":{"dateTime":"2020-06-13T11:00:00+05:30","timeZone":"Asia/Kolkata"},
  "end":{"dateTime":"2020-06-13T12:00:00+05:30","timeZone":"Asia/Kolkata"},
  "attendees":[
    {"email":"attendee1@gmail.com"},
    {"email":"attendee2@gmail.com","organizer":true}
  ],
  "reminders":{
    "useDefault":false,
    "overrides":[{"method":"email","minutes":10},{"method":"popup","minutes":10}]
  },
  "creator": {
    "email": "attendee2@gmail.com",
    "self": true
  },
  "organizer":{
    "email":"attendee2@gmail.com",
    "self":true
  }
}
```

I want to make attendees as the organizer so that he can start the meeting.
Am I missing something in request payload? or do I need to grant them permission?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### By default it is the person who runs the code (and authenticates as himself) who will be set as the creator and organizer

- `creator` and `organizer` are read-only values, as you can read [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource)
- If you want to make somebody else than yourself the event owner / organizer, you need to use a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) with [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)
- This would allow you to authenticate as the user and act on his behalf
- Creating the event om behalf of the user will automatically make him the event owner and organizer
- Note that with a service account you can only impersonate users if they are from the same domain like you