# Google calendar api - how to give an outside user the role of the organizer

Tags: google-calendar-api

- We have a service account creating meetings from our node.js backend. Each meeting has a Google Meet link generated. Attendees are NOT associated with our gsuite account.
- However, each attendee is required to “ask to join” the meeting when they click on the Google Meet link.
  With the service account, when the meeting has been created the creator and organizer are both automatically set to the service account user despite the parameters that passed in the “insert” function.

We need to generate meetings and assign the role of the organizer to one of the attendees to give one of the attendees the privilege to start the meeting and let the other attendees in. How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

### Two things:

1. If you user a service account - the only type of delegation that is possible is **domain-wide** delegation. In other words, the service account is not able to impersonate a user who does not belong to the same domain.
2. If you do not user a service account with impersonation - the `creator` / `organizer` of an event is the person who runs the code to create the event. Those properties are `readonly` and cannot be modified - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62384406/11599789).

**Now, as for letting external users join a Google Meet without approval - have a read at the [information provided by Google](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9303069?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop):**

> Who needs to request to join a video meeting?
>
> People who aren’t added to the Calendar event.
>
> Web users only - People who don't have a Google Account. This is applicable for meetings created by G Suite users. For any meetings created by non G Suite users, you will need a Google account to request joining the meeting.
>
> G Suite users only: People outside your organization who use G Suite for Education. Anyone in the meeting can grant access. Someone from your organization in the video meeting can also grant access.

Provided that the guests confirmed their participation in the event, I recommend you to contact GSuite support to troubleshoot why your invitees are not able to join the meeting without approval.

### WORKAROUND

Consider creating an account in your GSuite domain for the users whom you would like to allow to join wihtout aproval.